# Google speech recognition and Voicexml

Tags: difference, google-voice, voicexml

Hi guys i googled about voicexml and google speech recognition but i didn't understand if google speech recognition model is based on voicexml model or not.

If possible, can you tell me the differences please?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to move this question, but it would've been great for the Data Science StackExchange board.

Comment: I just mean that voice recognition is a part of Data Science and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/  is a younger StackExchange board that is eager for good questions like this, whereas on StackOverflow people like me welcome your question but others may say that it's not strictly a programming question and thus doesn't belong. I'm writing an answer to your question now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Voice Search (as it is sometimes called) is **closed source**, thus it's hard to say what it's based on or how their algorithms differ. If you click [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software) you'll find a list and comparison of many voice recognition implementations, including Google's and VoiceXML.

If it does have anything to do with Verbio's VoiceXML then Verbio is likely under a contractual agreement not to disclose that as there's no mention of Google anywhere on [their website](http://www.verbio.com/en/buscar?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=google).